# How does python handle exceptional situations?

Tags: python, exception

I learnt about using the except function to prevent your code from crashing but I want to understand it better on how python executes it.

For example, I have code that adds a pair of numbers and if the variable nums has more than two numbers it should give AssertionError.

```
1    def sum_pair(pair):
2        assert len(pair) == 2
3        return pair[0] + pair[1]

4    try:
5        total = sum_pair(nums)
6        print 'The total is', total
7    except AssertionError:
8        print 'Abort'
```

So from my view python executes Lines 1, 2, 4, 5, 7 and 8 only.
Is this correct way to understand it?

Thank you

Comment: The statements inside a function aren't executed until you call the function. So line 2 won't be executed until after line 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When an exception is signalled, the call stack is searched for a `try` block that has an `except` clause that matches the type of the exception. The stack is unwound to that point, the code in the `except` clause is executed, and then execution continues after the `try` block.

So when line 2 detects that the assertion has failed, it immediately exits the `sum_pair()` function and executes the code starting from line 8.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, it executes Lines 4,5,1,2,7,8 in that order.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the OP realizes that and was just sorting the executed line numbers. Additionally, this answer would be more suitable as a comment.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3, Fair enough. When I read the question, I interpreted it as OP wanting to know if the execution order was the *correct way to understand it*, but your point is well taken.

Comment: IMHO, the `def` line is executed first, so that the identificator `sum_pair` is knows to the interpretor. So the order of execution is 1,4,5,2,7,8